# How to paint a good RGB color map?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to paint a full RGB color map that eventually will allow a user to select a color by tapping that visual map at any point. My current code is the following:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for (float x=0; x<320; x++) {
        for (float y=0; y<416; y++) {

            float r = x / 320;
            float g = y / 416;
            float b = (y < 208) ? y / 208 : (416 - y) / 208;

            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, r, g, b, 1.0);
            CGContextFillRect(c, CGRectMake(x, y, 1, 1));

        }
    }
}
```

The result is not too bad but I'm not satisfied yet. The spectrum misses bright colors including white. The reason is clear: red, green and blue will never reach 1.0 at the same time.

[image: Screenshot of the resulting color map]

*Do you have any advise how to improve that map so it represents the full spectrum of the RGB color space?*

Thanks for all your input!

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by *Josh Caswell* I've used the HSB color space and the following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    int size = 20;

    for (float x=0; x<320; x+=size) {

        float s = x < 160 ? 1       : (320 - x) / 160;
        float b = x < 160 ? x / 160 : 1;

        for (float y=0; y<416; y+=size) {

            float h = y / 416;

            [[UIColor colorWithHue:h saturation:s brightness:b alpha:1.0] setFill];
            CGContextFillRect(c, CGRectMake(x, y, size, size));
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following output which is perfect for my needs.

[image: Result using HSB color space]

Thanks for all input!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code; that came out really nicely!

Comment: The final result is indeed beautiful. I hope nobody ever requires a gray; you might want to do a series of grays along the right side.

Comment: That's a good addition. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you're trying to flatten a three-dimensional object onto a plane. An RGB color basically represents a point inside of a cube. Mapping the RGB solid onto a surface may be mathematically possible, but probably won't be particularly intuitive for this color-selection purpose.

You might have better luck using HSB, which is more like a cylinder with hue as angle around the circumference. You could "unroll" the cylinder, mapping hue to the y coordinate, then vary either brightness or saturation along the x axis -- you can do some simple testing to decide which component is more important for your application. A two-finger-swipe could be used for the third component if you felt it was necessary to include it.

HSB with saturation on X-axis:
[image: HSB map; S on X axis]

With brightness on X-axis:
[image: HSB map; B on X axis]

With saturation and brightness equal and both on X-axis:
[image: HSB map; S=B on X axis]

If you need white, which occurs when S = 0%, B = 100%, you could either stick a strip along one side, or try S = 1/B.

Comment: The swipe gesture to change the 3rd component is a nice idea... but I want to keep it as simple as possible. So I'll stick to a flat representation that won't need any user interaction. HSB might be easier to flatten though... thanks.

Comment: HSB is much easier to handle. I've raised brightness from left to center and then lowered saturation from center to right. This results in the following (with squares of 20px): http://cl.ly/1f0q0m043u3v1O2s1618 - I'll add my final code.

Answer (score 2):

I think a way to derive it is such:

Horizontally, for each pixel, pick a ratio of r g b such as "0, 0, 1"

Draw pixels from top to bottom with a "brightness" that goes from 0 to 1.

Derive each pixel as `pixel = brightness * (r,g,b)`

As you go horizontally, iterate R G B as:

`000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111`

You can achieve this using an equation, and handle your interpolation at the same time, if you use 3 sine calculations.

This solves your problem of white and black, and gives you a lot of the color space.  If you need absolutely every pixel of the color space you need to do your horizontal interpolation differently and you'll need 2^8 instead of 8 control points.

Comment: That's a really nice idea... using sin() to interpolate from 0..1 and trying to span the whole spectrum horizontally - thanks for that input. I'll try to adapt it.

Comment: My current result looks like this: http://cl.ly/3v321G2m0V3o1c3n0n3c - I'll give HSB a try...

Comment: Didn't realize you had implemented it. I can't believe how ugly my idea came out! Thanks for sharing the screenshot.

Comment: The idea wasn't bad... but HSB simply gets it better :)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to represent a 3-dimensional color space on a 2-dimensional surface. It's unlikely that you'll find a single surface that is adequate.

You'll need a two-part selection.